# How to make OpenPGP Applet appear on Wingpanel?

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, openpgp

I try to use the "OpenPGP Applet" from the Elementary OS Software Center. But the Applet doesnt start when i try to start it via Doubleclick on the Icon. The little OpenPGP Applet Icon comes to Plank, but nothing happened on Wingpanel.
Autostart while Systemstart doesnt help. Can anybody help?

ElementaryOS "loki"

Greets

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it is not something that is going to work.

You cannot use this applet with Wingpanel, as it is not compatible with elementary OS, it has been developed for Gnome.